# String to Int32

Tags: c#

Есть строка 0xB368 (или, например, 0x9DA). Её нужно преобразовать в Int32. Пробовал отделить 0x с помощью Replace, но ничего не получилось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279892

```
string s = "0xB368";
int i = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString(s);
Console.WriteLine(i); // 45928
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("X")); // B368
```

---

```
string s = "0xB368";
Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("0x", "")); // B368
```

Comment: Вы не поняли, наверное. Мне нужно, чтобы переменная Int32 a приняла значение это. Именно B368. Т.е. нужно, чтобы получилось по итогу a = 0xB368

Comment: @Frehzy, 0xB368 равно 45928

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!